# Accessing private member using this pointer returned by shared_from_this

Tags: c++, memory-management, this, shared-ptr

I have an implementation which looks like this:

```
class A : public std::enable_shared_from_this<A>
{
public:
    A() {}
    void dummy(std::string name);

private:
    std::map<std::string, std::string> cache;
};

void
A::dummy(std::string name) {
    auto shared_this = shared_from_this();
    auto find =
        [name, shared_this] () {
            auto iter = shared_this->cache.find(name);
    };
}
```

I am not sure how this line works:
    auto iter = shared_this->cache.find(name);

It looks like we are trying to access the private member using a pointer to the class but I'm not sure if it works differently.

How does this work?

Comment: This is no problem. Since `dummy()` is a member of the class `A`, it can access any private member of any instance of `A`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A::dummy(std::string name)` is a member of the class `A`. And thus, from within this function, you have access to all `public`, `protected`, and `private` members for any instance of `A`. Here are relevant quotes from the standard:

> N4140 §11 [class.access]/1
>
> A member of a class can be:
>
> (1.1) — **private**; that is, **its name can be used only by members** and friends of the class in which it is declared.
>
> (1.2) — protected; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is
>   declared, by classes derived from that class, and by their friends (see 11.4).
>
> (1.3) — public; that is, its name can be used anywhere without access restriction.
>
> N4140 §11 [class.access]/2
>
> **A member of a class can also access all the names to which the class has access.** A local class of a member function may access the same names that the member function itself may access.

Answer (score 0):

> It looks like we are trying to access the private member using a pointer to the class but I'm not sure if it works differently.

Yes that is correct. Since `dummy()` is a member of `A`, it has access to all members of `A`, including private ones.